# Struct declared twice?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

When I try to compile a source file with the Tiny **C** Compiler, I get the following error:

```
arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:38: error: struct/union/enum already defined
```

Here are lines 9-68 in the header file ptrace.h, which my source file indirectly includes:

```
#ifdef __i386__

struct pt_regs {
    unsigned long bx;
    unsigned long cx;
    unsigned long dx;
    unsigned long si;
    unsigned long di;
    unsigned long bp;
    unsigned long ax;
    unsigned long ds;
    unsigned long es;
    unsigned long fs;
    unsigned long gs;
    unsigned long orig_ax;
    unsigned long ip;
    unsigned long cs;
    unsigned long flags;
    unsigned long sp;
    unsigned long ss;
};

#else /* __i386__ */

struct pt_regs {
/*
 * C ABI says these regs are callee-preserved. They aren't saved on kernel entry
 * unless syscall needs a complete, fully filled "struct pt_regs".
 */
    unsigned long r15;
    unsigned long r14;
    unsigned long r13;
unsigned long r12;
    unsigned long bp;
    unsigned long bx;
/* These regs are callee-clobbered. Always saved on kernel entry. */
    unsigned long r11;
    unsigned long r10;
    unsigned long r9;
    unsigned long r8;
    unsigned long ax;
unsigned long cx;
    unsigned long dx;
    unsigned long si;
    unsigned long di;
/*
 * On syscall entry, this is syscall#. On CPU exception, this is error code.
 * On hw interrupt, it's IRQ number:
 */
    unsigned long orig_ax;
/* Return frame for iretq */
    unsigned long ip;
    unsigned long cs;
    unsigned long flags;
    unsigned long sp;
    unsigned long ss;
/* top of stack page */
};

#endif /* !__i386__ */
```

By indirectly include, I mean that my source file includes a different header file that includes this header file.
The struct is not declared twice. What is going wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you are also including a different system header file, probably also indirectly, with the same content. Try using the `-E` option and searching the output for the struct definition; you should be able to trace the includes using the `# ` lines in the `-E` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put a -nostdinc flag in. The struct pt_regs is defined in a standard include file.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but try making a single declaration of the struct, but have only the *field* declarations inside the precompile directives.